# getting record from CoreData?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to add value to CoreData from .plist and get from coreData and show them on UITable. I made take from .plist and send them to CoreData .But I can't take them from CoreData `entity` and set to some `NSMutableArray`.. Here my codes

**Edit : SOLVED**

```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FakeData" 
                                                     ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSArray  *myArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 



FlickrFetcher *flickrfetcher =[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance];

managedObjectContext =[flickrfetcher managedObjectContext];

for(NSDictionary *dict in myArray){

    Photo *newPhoto = (Photo *)[NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo"
                                inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


    // set the attributes for the photo
    NSLog(@"Creating Photo: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
    [newPhoto setName:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [newPhoto setPath:[dict objectForKey:@"path"]];

    NSLog(@"Person is: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"user"]);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==%@",[dict objectForKey:@"user"]];
    NSMutableArray  *peopleArray =  (NSMutableArray *)[flickrfetcher
                                                       fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:predicate];



    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [peopleArray objectEnumerator];
    Person *person;
    BOOL exists = FALSE;

    while (person = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@" Person is: %@ ", person.name);
        if([person.name  isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"user"]]) {
            exists = TRUE;
            NSLog(@"-- Person Exists : %@--", person.name);
            [newPhoto setPerson:person];
        }
    }




    // if person does not already exist then add the person
    if (!exists) {
        Person *newPerson = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        // create the person
        [newPerson setName:[dict objectForKey:@"user"]];
        NSLog(@"-- Person Created : %@--", newPerson.name);

        // associate the person with the photo
        [newPhoto setPerson:newPerson];

    }

//THis IS myArray that I want to save value in it and them show them in UITABLE
personList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];






    NSLog(@"lllll  %@",[personList objectAtIndex:0]);
    // save the data
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);

    }
}

//To access core data objects you can try the following:


// setup our fetchedResultsController
fetchedResultsController = [flickrfetcher fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil];

// execute the fetch
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
}

// save our data //HERE PROBLEM THAT I DONW KNOW WHERE IT IS SAVING
//[personList addObject:(NSMutableArray *)[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]];

[self setPersonList:(NSMutableArray *)[fetchedResultsController
                                    fetchedObjects]];


}
```

Here my `tableView` function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"ss %d",[personList count]);

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[personList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



// Set up the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what errors you're seeing or the value of the NSLog statements you've included.  Why don't you add more debug statements and show us the values.

Comment: I dont get any error.Problem is I dont know how to set value from CoreData to my  personList .. 
I know how to add to array like  [personList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SAMPLE"]];  
But how will I added value from CoreData to personList I cant figure out it.

Comment: If you have solved this then post it as an answer and accept the answer so that the question is shown to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution.I created an NSMutable array and used setPeopleList to add values from fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects.Also to use set operation I created my array in header file and added

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *peopleList;
```

and in .m file i created

```
   @synthesize peopleList;
```

and  I used

```
[self setPeopleList:(NSMutableArray *)[fetchedResultsController
                                    fetchedObjects]];
```

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` returns an `NSArray` not a `NSMutableArray`.  Casting that return is dangerous at best. You are better off creating a `-mutableCopy` of the returned array to guarantee that it is in fact mutable.